# Как получить путь к папке с помощью Intent на Android

Tags: java, android

Для получения файла использую:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

Но встал вопрос как получить папку/директорию..

API level 19.

Есть ли способы сделать это без сторонних библиотек?